# Can't SSHing to Ubuntu via hostname and port other than 22

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to connect to Ubuntu via SSH from OS X, and I took the same step as explained in this page (https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html). After setting it, I tried to connect by the form of `username@ip_address`, then it was successful and I was able to be in Ubuntu from OS X Terminal (this time I used port 22). However, when I tried to SSH to Ubuntu by the form of `username@hostname`, then I couldn't and the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname my_user_name: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` occurred. I also tried to connect via port 2222 by changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then it failed too by spitting out the error `debug1: connect to address my_ip_address port 22: Connection refused` (this time I tried to connect by IP address).

So I think the latter issue stems from the fact that I have to make some sort of modifications also on OS X, but don't know where/how to do and don't know it's true in the first place.

The former issue is more annoying, as I'm not sure whether I could understand it correctly. I used `hostname` as the value that I got from running `hostname` on Ubuntu Terminal...but is it right? And when I searched for the issue on the Web, I knew that it's from DNS issue...but don't know what it is and how to fix it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Terminal on OS X when using ssh to establish a remote connection using a hostname on a local network, add the suffix `.local` such that the command reads `ssh username@hostname.local`  If you need to override the default port 22, as your example of using port 2222, add `-p 2222` to the command. You can also set this up in Terminal's "New Remote Connection.." dialog (Command-Shift-K) for easy access.

Comment: Thanks. I succeeded by either adding `.local` suffix as you suggested or modifying `/private/etc/hosts` Alaa suggested in the above post. Which is the better way? I guess yours is better because IP address changes once I reboot my Ubuntu... but I'm not sure.

Comment: With changing IP addresses, the `.local` option will ensure that you can connect regardless of the machine IP. Even though my server is on a reserved IP, I still use the `.local` option using the hostname.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and it's not terribly surprising as `local` isn't the name of my (private, internal) domain. Interestingly, I *am* able to connect to other hosts by hostname via SSH on the same network.

Comment: @KennyEvitt So, you're running an internal DNS server?

Comment: @douggro, yes, effectively; my router provides DNS. What's particularly strange is that both `host` and `nslookup` resolve the problematic host.

Comment: @KennyEvitt I could see the machine not responding to a `.local` query if there was no mDNS service installed. IS your router hosting a legit BIND zone, or some other host caching scheme?

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `ssh username@hostname`, the computer that you are connecting from (your Mac OS) does not know the IP of this `hostname`, that' why it's telling you that `ssh: Could not resolve hostname`. So, what you need to do is tell your Mac that this `hostname` is this `ip_address`. To do this on your Mac, [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-edit-the-mac-os-x-hosts-file-and-why-you-might-want-to/) page tells you how to do it. Basically, what you need to do is `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` (`sudo nano /etc/hosts` on Mac OS X 10.7 and higher), and add a line at the end of the file like this:

```
ip_address       hostname
```

With the actual IP and hostname of your Ubuntu machine. Once done, Control+O, then Enter, then Control+X to save and close the file. Then do `dscacheutil -flushcache` for the changes to take effect. Now, when you do `ssh username@hostname`, it should work.

*And about that port 2222:*

You're right, you have to do some modification on Mac OS...well, it's just a couple more characters. When you do `ssh username@hostname`, what is actually happening in the background is `ssh username@hostname -p22`, because port 22 is the default SSH port. But, if you know that the machine you are trying to connect to is using a different port, you'll have to manually specify it. So, since you've changed the port on Ubuntu to 2222, you'll have to do `ssh username@hostname -p2222`. This has nothing to do with using the `hostname` or `ip_address`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I've been able to run it successfully, both on hostname and port issue. I want to ask one more question... Running `ssh username@hostname -p2222` every time when I want to SSH is a bit tiresome... what or how do you (or the community convention) do to cope with the issue? I came up with creating an alias, but is it the best way?

Comment: The problem with using an alias is (I think) you won't be able to specify another port if you wish to connect to another machine. Here's a better way: not sure if it's the same file on Mac, but edit the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (note, it's `ssh_config`, not `sshd_config`) on your Mac and add the line `Port 2222` in the end. This will make the default SSH port 2222. However, you can just change back the port to 22 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I found the file in `/etc/ssh_config`, so I think it is what you pointed to. If I change from port 22 to 2222 in the file, then it means every time I execute `ssh` command, I always use port 2222 as default...right? And it also means when I try to connect to another machine which doesn't use port 2222, then I have to add -p argument to connect to the specific machine...right?

Comment: Yes. Also, don't forget to mark an answer as [your accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate to others that the question has been solved.

Comment: Yeah, I know I should mark accepted answer but still wonder which is better between yours and douggro's...

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to point it out because some people just come in, ask a question, and run away =). Also, I never knew that `.local` always worked. But of course, `.local` is definitely the better way because of dynamic IPs.

Comment: @Alaa Yes, the `.local` directs the connection to the local network for hostname resolution. Works in web browsers too: I connect to my Webmin instance using it.